# Vulkan's transfer queue family capabilities and video card support: Are the condition checks accurate?

Tags: c++, specifications, vulkan

I am following this [Vulkan Youtube video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_LWbfs1cOU&index=17&list=PLxNGvnKpZBcVyjXg7Ko9RcAy9Nt-SmS1J&t=11s) by Joshua Shucker. I'm currently on his 14th video where he is working on creating a secondary queue family for the vertex buffer. This focuses on the staging process for vertex buffers. My code matches that of his in his video except that of a `cout statement` in which I added for testing. Here is the function and structure for the Queue Families:

```
struct QueueFamilyIndices {
    int graphicsFamily = -1;
    int transferFamily = -1;

    bool isComplete() {
        return (graphicsFamily >= 0 && transferFamily >= 0);
    }
};

QueueFamilyIndices FindQueueFamilies( const VkPhysicalDevice* device, const VkSurfaceKHR* surface ) {
    QueueFamilyIndices indices;
    uint32_t queueFamilyCount = 0;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties( *device, &queueFamilyCount, nullptr );
    std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queueFamilies( queueFamilyCount );
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties( *device, &queueFamilyCount, queueFamilies.data() );

    int i = 0;
    for( const auto &queueFamily : queueFamilies ) {
        VkBool32 presentSupport = false;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR( *device, i, *surface, &presentSupport );

        if( queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && (queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) && presentSupport ) {
            indices.graphicsFamily = i;
        }

        if( queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && (queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_TRANSFER_BIT) && 
            !(queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) && presentSupport ) {
            indices.transferFamily = i;
        }

        if( indices.isComplete() ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if( indices.graphicsFamily >= 0 && indices.transferFamily == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "Graphics family found, transfer family missing: using graphics family" << std::endl;
        indices.transferFamily = indices.graphicsFamily;
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Within this function `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(...)` is being called twice since there are 2 queue families that have been found after `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(...)` has been called to populate the vector of `VkQueueFamilyProperties` structures.

---

Here is the specs for my `NVidia GeForce gtx 750 Ti` card based on `Vulkan's` specifications for its queue families: [Vulkan:Report](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/displayreport.php?id=3155#queuefamilies) and in case the link changes over time here is the information directly:

> ```
> Queue family                          0     
> queueCount                            16 
> flags                                 GRAPHICS_BIT
>                                       COMPUTE_BIT
>                                       TRANSFER_BIT
>                                       SPARSE_BINDING_BIT 
> timestampValidBits                    64 
> minImageTransferGranularity.width     1 
> minImageTransferGranularity.height    1
> minImageTransferGranularity.depth     1 
> supportsPresent                       1 
>
> Queue family                          1 
> queueCount                            1 
> flags                                 TRANSFER_BIT
> timestampValidBits                    64 
> minImageTransferGranularity.width     1 
> minImageTransferGranularity.height    1 
> minImageTransferGranularity.depth     1 
> supportsPresent                       0
> ```

Now according to these specs which coincide with the values in my vector of structs while I'm stepping through the debugger my structures are populated with
the values of:

```
 queueFamilies[0].queueFlags = 15;
 queueFamilies[0].queueCount = 16;
 queueFamilies[0].timestampValidBits = 64;
 queueFamilies[0].minImageTransferGranularity = { width = 1, height = 1, depth = 1 };

 queueFamilies[1].queueFlags = 4;
 queueFamilies[1].queueCount = 1;
 queueFamilies[1].timestampValidBits = 64;
 queueFamilies[1].minImageTransferGranularity = { width = 1, height = 1, depth = 1 };
```

So this appears to me that my card does support a separate `queueFamily` specifically the `transferFamily`.

---

Based on my assumption of this support and stepping through this function he has two if statements to check for valid conditions within the for loop for each of the indexed `queueFamily` objects. The if statements are returning exactly as they should be. My code compiles and builds without any errors or warnings, and it still does render then triangle when I'm not running it through the debugger and it does exit with a code of (0). So the code appears to be fine. However I'm not getting the results that I would at least be expecting.

I'm not sure if there is a bug in his code that he happened to missed, if I'm misinterpreting my video card's support of this Vulkan functionality, or if this could be either a Vulkan API bug or NVidia Driver bug.

However as I was stepping through this function to find out why the `indices.transferFamily` variable was not being set to `i`; I noticed that on the second iteration of the loop it has nothing to do with the presence of the `transferFamilyQueue`, its parameter values, or flags. What is causing this if statement to return false is the `presentSupport` variable as it is being set to `0` on the second call which does match the data sheet above. So the output is as expected.

> My question then becomes: Is there an actual implementation problem with the condition checking in the second if statement?

This is where I'm stuck as I am a bit confused because we are checking to see if there is a `transferQueueFamily` available and if so use that to create and use a `stagingBuffer` to copy the contents from the CPU to the GPU for the `vertex buffer(s)`. From what I can see it appears my card does have this `transferFamily` but does not have `supportPresent` for this family. However, when thinking about it; if you are using a `transferFamily` - `transferQueue` you wouldn't want to `present` it directly as you'll just be copying the data from a temporary `vertexBuffer` on the CPU to the `vertexBuffer` that will be used on the GPU. So I'm wondering if the final check in this if statement is correct or not. If my assumptions about how Vulkan is working here is incorrect please don't hesitate to correct me as this is my first attempt at getting a `Vulkan` rendering application working.

Answer (score 2):

There's no Vulkan API or NVidia Driver bug. It's right there in your report sheet:

> `supportsPresent                       0`

E.g. AMD does seem to support presents on `VK_QUEUE_TRANSFER_BIT` queue families, but it is purely optional (31.4. Querying for WSI Support):

> Not all physical devices will include WSI support. Within a physical device, not all queue families will support presentation.

Comment: Yeah I was originally assuming that and that it was the provider of the tutorial that was in err, but I don't like to make assumptions without knowing for sure. I've had some experience in both OpenGL and DirectX and Vulkan is a complete different beast! It's quite a bit of a curve to get it initialized and running properly for both your application needs - uses and the current hardware you'll be supporting, but the trade offs are completely worth it in the end via performance reasons and other concepts such as the API helps to keep the drivers less error prone. Thank you for the feed back.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Well, tutorial-makers are people too. Tutorials are a good source of frequently parroted errors... I mean, the code snippet has other small problems. Vulkan is not a perf silver bullet (you have to know what you are doing; better so than the OpenGL driver would know), but I personally like the API design much better (for non-perf reasons). Except the "Cap hell" combinatorial explosion most of the setup code is just filling `struct`s (i.e. things I would not even count), and it levels off (and even reverses); watch: https://youtu.be/0R23npUCCnw?t=10m28s

Answer (score 1):

There's no good reason to be checking `presentSupport` when searching for a transfer specific queue.  This is likely a copy and paste error *somewhere*.  Typically you don't care if anything other than the graphics queue has support for presentation.

You **do** want to use a transfer queue that **does *not*** have the graphics bit set, as such a queue is likely to correspond to dedicated transfer hardware that will not impact the performance of work being done on the graphics queue.

Comment: Yeah I was sort of thinking the same thing; but I haven't received a reply from the maker of the video yet. Just needed some kind of confirmation and assurance. So i could see checking for this when trying to create a physical or logical device and for when creating a surface and or swap chain to use, but once you have all of that information yeah it does seem redundant to check again for the presentSupport after you already have your graphics rendering device already selected. I'll try removing that last condition in both if statements and see how the application performs.

Comment: Well, never say never. Can't know when it can come in handy. Technically `vkQueuePresentKHR` is allowed on a Transfer queue. And technically async Transfer queue can impact performance of Graphics queue in a way. AFAIK for some things Graphics Queue does use the services of Copy Engines, which means contesting the same computational resource.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a few good answers here and doing some more testing on my end I think I have found an appropriate solution to the application code design. This function is called about 4 or 5 times throughout the application by other functions. It is called when `Vulkan` is being initialized, it is called again when rating the devices' suitability for choosing the best possible device that is available, it is also being called when creating the logical device, and so forth.

All of these initial calls typically only need the `queueFamily's` count and or index values to make sure that a suitable graphics device with a `queueFamily` is available for graphics processing and rendering.

However when this function is being called to create an arbitrary buffer that will be used as a staging buffer for an existing dedicated transfer queue this time we actually need the family queue and all of its properties. So to fix this problem; when checking for the `graphicsQueue` I left this last condition check to see if `presentSupport` is available, as for when the for loop iterates to the next index to check for the dedicated `transferQueue`, I omitted this condition check for the `presentSupport` all together.

```
QueueFamilyIndices FindQueueFamilies( const VkPhysicalDevice* device, const VkSurfaceKHR* surface ) {
    QueueFamilyIndices indices;
    uint32_t queueFamilyCount = 0;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties( *device, &queueFamilyCount, nullptr );
    std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queueFamilies( queueFamilyCount );
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties( *device, &queueFamilyCount, queueFamilies.data() );

    int i = 0;
    for( const auto &queueFamily : queueFamilies ) {
        VkBool32 presentSupport = false;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR( *device, i, *surface, &presentSupport );

        if( queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && (queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) && presentSupport ) {
            indices.graphicsFamily = i;
        }

        if( queueFamily.queueCount > 0 && (queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_TRANSFER_BIT) && 
            !(queueFamily.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) /*&& presentSupport*/ ) {
            indices.transferFamily = i;
        }

        if( indices.isComplete() ) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if( indices.graphicsFamily >= 0 && indices.transferFamily == -1 ) {
        std::cout << "Graphics family found, transfer family missing: using graphics family" << std::endl;
        indices.transferFamily = indices.graphicsFamily;
    }

    return indices;
}
```

Now not only is the `indices.transferFamily` being set to `i` on the 2<sup>nd</sup> iteration; the check for `indices.isComplete()` is also returning true and the last if statement for the roll back is now returning false. Everything seems to being rendering properly without issue. It appears that the `staging buffers` are being copied over to the `GPU` now instead of using the `CPU` for the `vertex buffer` objects.

Comment: "*This function is called about 4 or 5 times throughout the application by other functions.*" Um... why? In order for the answers to change, someone would have to physically add or remove hardware. The fact that this function is being called so much suggests confusion on the part of your code.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm following an online tutorial and that is how they have the code. I'm just following through it until I get a good feel for Vulkan. Once I'm familiar with Vulkan I'll go back and refactor the code.